# Change returned value from jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using `jQuery datetimepicker` where I am formatting date like `DD/MM/YYYY`, everything is okay with displayed date, but when I sent it on `post` I want date to be sent as  `2022-07-22`, when I use `HTML5` `datepicker` the date is sent `2022-07-22`. How I can do that? Do I need to do it on `controller` side or I can do it using `datetimepicker` and `moment` on client side.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment');
  $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
     timepicker: false,          
     format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment');
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: dateFormat,
    });
});

$('.getByVal').on('click', function () {
    //get value by using textbox value
    let value = $('.datepicker').val();
    console.log('By jquery val: ' + value);
});

$('.getByDateTimePicker').on('click', function () {
    //get Date object by using datetimepicker and convert into required format with the help of moment
    let value = moment($('.datepicker').datetimepicker('getValue')).format(dateFormat);
    console.log('By datetimepicker getValue: ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
<button class="getByVal">Get Value By Val</button>
<button class="getByDateTimePicker">Get Value By Datetimepicker</button>
```